# Cannot ping another computer connected by line from main computer which's physical network card is bound by hyper-v network

Tags: windows, macos, hyper-v

**Computer A (Main Computer, Windows 11, installed Hyper-V):**
10G LAN PORT1: 192.168.100.1
WIFI: 192.168.50.17
Hyper-V bound detail:
[image]
**Computer B (Another Computer, MACOS):**
10G LAN PORT: 192.168.100.100
WIFI: 192.168.50.124

**Route Table In [A]:**

```
===========================================================================
接口列表
  8...14 dd a9 d2 aa e1 ......QLogic BCM57840 10 Gigabit Ethernet (NDIS VBD Client)
 25...14 dd a9 d2 aa df ......QLogic BCM57840 10 Gigabit Ethernet (NDIS VBD Client) #2
 33...00 15 5d d7 d5 88 ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
 64...00 15 5d 06 d4 4e ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #7
 28...14 dd a9 d2 aa de ......Intel(R) I210 Gigabit Network Connection #2
 27...fc 77 74 eb 9a 11 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
 12...fe 77 74 eb 9a 10 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
  4...fc 77 74 eb 9a 10 ......Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9260 160MHz
 23...00 1a 7d da 71 11 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
 40...14 dd a9 d2 aa dd ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 21...00 15 5d 2a 48 da ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
 41...00 15 5d 38 74 6d ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #4
 57...00 15 5d 30 65 d7 ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #6
 59...00 15 5d f6 9f 0b ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #8
===========================================================================

IPv4 路由表
===========================================================================
活动路由:
网络目标        网络掩码          网关       接口   跃点数
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.50.1    192.168.50.17    291
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0            在链路上         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255            在链路上         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上         127.0.0.1    331
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0            在链路上    169.254.62.251    281
   169.254.62.251  255.255.255.255            在链路上    169.254.62.251    281
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上    169.254.62.251    281
      172.17.16.0    255.255.240.0            在链路上       172.17.16.1   5256
      172.17.16.1  255.255.255.255            在链路上       172.17.16.1   5256
    172.17.31.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上       172.17.16.1   5256
      172.17.48.0    255.255.240.0            在链路上       172.17.48.1   5256
      172.17.48.1  255.255.255.255            在链路上       172.17.48.1   5256
    172.17.63.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上       172.17.48.1   5256
     172.26.192.0    255.255.240.0            在链路上      172.26.192.1   5256
     172.26.192.1  255.255.255.255            在链路上      172.26.192.1   5256
   172.26.207.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上      172.26.192.1   5256
     172.30.128.0    255.255.240.0            在链路上      172.30.128.1    271
     172.30.128.1  255.255.255.255            在链路上      172.30.128.1    271
   172.30.143.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上      172.30.128.1    271
     172.30.176.0    255.255.240.0            在链路上      172.30.176.1   5256
     172.30.176.1  255.255.255.255            在链路上      172.30.176.1   5256
   172.30.191.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上      172.30.176.1   5256
      172.31.80.0    255.255.240.0            在链路上       172.31.80.1    271
      172.31.80.1  255.255.255.255            在链路上       172.31.80.1    271
    172.31.95.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上       172.31.80.1    271
     192.168.50.0    255.255.255.0            在链路上     192.168.50.17    291
    192.168.50.17  255.255.255.255            在链路上     192.168.50.17    291
   192.168.50.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上     192.168.50.17    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0            在链路上         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0            在链路上      172.30.176.1   5256
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0            在链路上      172.26.192.1   5256
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0            在链路上    169.254.62.251    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0            在链路上       172.17.16.1   5256
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0            在链路上       172.17.48.1   5256
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0            在链路上     192.168.50.17    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0            在链路上      172.30.128.1    271
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0            在链路上       172.31.80.1    271
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上      172.30.176.1   5256
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上      172.26.192.1   5256
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上    169.254.62.251    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上       172.17.16.1   5256
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上       172.17.48.1   5256
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上     192.168.50.17    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上      172.30.128.1    271
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255            在链路上       172.31.80.1    271
===========================================================================
永久路由:
  网络地址          网络掩码  网关地址  跃点数
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.50.1     默认
===========================================================================
```

First:
**In Computer B:**

1. Add 192.168.100.0 route rule:
   `route add 192.168.100.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.100.1`

Then I can get a pong from `Computer A` and can upload file or download file from it.

**Route Table in [B]:**

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags           Netif Expire
default            192.168.50.1       UGScg             en1
default            192.168.100.1      UGScIg            en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS               lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH                lo0
169.254            link#17            UCS               en1      !
169.254            link#20            UCSI              en0      !
169.254            link#28            UCSI             en10      !
169.254            link#29            UCSI             en11      !
169.254.44.240     fc:77:74:eb:9a:10  UHLSW             en1      !
169.254.62.251     14:dd:a9:d2:aa:de  UHLSW             en0      !
169.254.93.118/32  link#29            UCS              en11      !
169.254.163.210    de:52:85:20:60:72  UHLSW            en10      !
169.254.229.126/32 link#28            UCS              en10      !
192.168.50         link#17            UCS               en1      !
192.168.50.1/32    link#17            UCS               en1      !
192.168.50.1       7c:10:c9:e5:c4:88  UHLWIir           en1   1199
192.168.50.3       link#17            UHRLWIi           en1      !
192.168.50.4       26:71:ea:1c:38:21  UHLWIi            en1    825
192.168.50.17      fc:77:74:eb:9a:10  UHLWI             en1      !
192.168.50.50      62:7e:97:d2:c4:77  UHLWI             en1   1197
192.168.50.67      c4:dd:57:e9:61:8c  UHLWI             en1   1173
192.168.50.98      18:26:49:70:91:67  UHLWI             en1   1173
192.168.50.107     62:7e:97:d2:c4:77  UHLWI             en1      !
192.168.50.110     link#17            UHLWI             en1      !
192.168.50.155/32  link#17            UCS               en1      !
192.168.50.155     9c:76:e:3f:cb:25   UHLWI             lo0
192.168.100        link#20            UCS               en0      !
192.168.100.1/32   link#20            UCS               en0      !
192.168.100.1      link#20            UHLWIir           en0      !
192.168.100.100/32 link#20            UCS               en0      !
224.0.0/4          link#17            UmCS              en1      !
224.0.0/4          link#20            UmCSI             en0      !
224.0.0/4          link#28            UmCSI            en10      !
224.0.0/4          link#29            UmCSI            en11      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI            en1
239.192.152.143    1:0:5e:40:98:8f    UHmLWI            en1
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI            en1
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI            en0
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI           en10
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI           en11
255.255.255.255/32 link#17            UCS               en1      !
255.255.255.255/32 link#20            UCSI              en0      !
255.255.255.255/32 link#28            UCSI             en10      !
255.255.255.255/32 link#29            UCSI             en11      !
```

Sencond:
**In Computer A:**

1. Add 192.168.100.0 route rule:
   `route delete 0.0.0.0 192.168.100.0`
   `route add 192.168.100.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.100.1`

Then B cannot connect to A anymore though I reset the route table in Computer A.

**What I want:**

1. A and B can surf the internet from the subnet 192.168.50.x
2. A can connect to B, B can connect to A from the subnet 192.168.100.x
3. the vm installed in hypverV in A can connect to A\B\internet

Comment: What are all the manual route deleting / adding for? Why would you add an indirect route (i.e. route with a gateway / nexthop) for LAN subnet when the two hosts are attached to the same LAN / broadcast domain?

Comment: @TomYan the 192.168.100/24 subnet has no access to internet